# How to compare symbols in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to I compare symbols in javascript? I have a left arrow in my program and this is not working:

```
<input type="button" id="backspace" value="&#8592" />
document.getElementById("backspace").onclick=function (){display_ctrl(this.value);};
function display_ctrl(parameter){
      if (parameter=="&#8592"){alert("this is a left arrow");}
```

How can I compare whether it is particular symbol?

Comment: Proper HTML entities start with a `&` and end with a `;`.

Comment: have you tried by simply comparing "<" like `if (parameter=="<"){ }`. Or try "&lt;"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Unicode instead - `"\u2190"` is a left arrow.

```
> "&#8592"
"&#8592"
> "\u2190"
"←"
```

Your code would then become (I have formatted it to be more readable):

```
document.getElementById("backspace").onclick = function() {
    display_ctrl(this.value);
}
function display_ctrl(parameter) {
    if (parameter == "\u2190") {
        alert("this is a left arrow");
    }
}
```

Comment: One more question; on callback, display_ctrl and function(){display_ctrl()} means the same thing right?

Comment: @Jack_of_All_Trades Yes. You can use the second method if you want to call the function with arguments.

Answer (score 1):

A left arrow? So you took an arrow to your script, didn't you?

Joke aside. Why don't you just compare the sign?

```
if (parameter == '\u2190') 
    alert('Left arrow!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your callback is wrong, you need to pass the callback reference to `onclick` property, not the value returned by `display_ctrl` in this case `undefined`

```
document.getElementById("backspace").onclick=display_ctrl;
function display_ctrl(){
    var parameter = this.value
    if (parameter=="&#8592"){
        alert("this is a left arrow");
    }
}
```

Comment: Please see the edit..Do you still think my callback is wrong? I have done the same for all of my code...

Comment: But that was the problem. Edit did not worked until I changed it to unicode like other suggested.